# How do I convert a DateTime SELECT in Entity Framework 5 to only SELECT the date portion?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

This is not working:

```
select new Schedules
{
    airDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(schedules.DateSched),
};
```

schedules.DateSched is type "SQL DateTime".

The above function is returning the date AND time portion of it.

How do I go about assign only the DATE part of schedules.DateSched to my "airDate" variable?

This is what Entity Framework produces:

```
convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), <field>, 102) ,  102) AS [C4]
```

And if you select that, you get:

2013-06-24 00:00:00.0000000

I want to get:

06/24/2013

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's returning the time or are you just seeing `00:00` or `12:00 AM` in a display somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the answers helped me so what I did was, in the actual gridView, I did:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Air Date" DataField="AirDate" SortExpression="AirDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}"/>
```

Comment: Not for nothing, none of the answers helped *you* precisely because you left out the highly relevant information that you needed this format for a grid view.  The `DataFormatString` has the same effect as the string argument to `DateTime.ToString(string format)` that everyone was trying to explain to you.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you get out of SQL is irrelevant to your question: C# only has a `DateTime` type. There's no `Date`(only) type in C# to convert to. As such, `2013-06-24 00:00:00.00000` is the closest you'll get to having a Date without a time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried formatting the date?

```
   airDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(schedules.DateSched).ToString("d", 
                      CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))),
```

Comment: Method ToSring has 0 parameters but it is invoked with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` type *always* has a time component.  All `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` does is strip off any time value, effectively changing the time component to midnight.

If you only want to *display* the date component, than use an appropriate format code to display just the date:

```
string myDate = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I can't use the ToString function in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: You don't use that on the _entity_ - you use it when you _display_ the data.  Since you didn't specify how you're doing that I gave a generic example.